# Is the Raspberry Pi 5 manufactured in accordance with ISO 9001:2015?

Tags: pi-5

I'm putting together a pilot study and it was suggested to me that I use a raspberry pi 5.

Ideally, all our equipment used should be manufactured by an OEM/ CM with a QMS in compliance with ISO 9001:2015 used during their manufacturing process.

I looked on the Raspberry Pi site and found [this](https://pip.raspberrypi.com/categories/704-manufacturing-iso-9001).  It is Sony's ISO 9001:2015 certification.

Looking [further](https://magpi.raspberrypi.com/articles/where-raspberry-pis-are-made) it appears the vast majority of RPs are manufactured in Wales

> Pencoed is not a big town, having a population of under 10,000.
> However, big things come out of there. It’s where you’ll find the Sony
> UK Technology Centre, one part factory where the vast majority of
> Raspberry Pis are made

The vast majority is not the same as all raspberry pis.

Does anyone know if all manufacturing of Raspberry PI 5s is done in accordance with ISO 9001:2015?

Comment: Pretty sure that the top tier of Pi distributors (eg. RS and Farnell) had or have licences to oversee their own production, and so historically this happened various places (eg. China).  I do not think the details of those deals are public though, so there is probably no way for you to ascertain this unless you pick a supplier and work the way up their chain; I'd presume this is information they'd be happy to confirm *if* they are compliant.

Answer (score 1):

You've asked a reasonable question - but in the **wrong place**. The place to find such information is through the [Industrial section of the RPi website](https://www.raspberrypi.com/for-industry/).

But apparently the answer to your question is, "Yes" - at least according to this [brief blurb](https://pip.raspberrypi.com/categories/704-manufacturing-iso-9001).

Comment: that link is in my question.  It's Sony's certificate and they manufacture the majority but that doesn't mean all as per my question...

Comment: @SeanJ: At least you know where to go for an answer now.  But now that you mention it... why did you ask the question if you already knew the answer?

Comment: I don't know the answer as per last 2 paragraph,s "The vast majority is not the same as all raspberry pis.

Does anyone know if all manufdacturing of Rapberry PI 5 s is done in accordance with ISO 9001:2015?"

Comment: @SeanJ:  So - do you want me to look up the phone number for ya'??